# How to on Import PEP8 the Package

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I am importing a module from a 3rd party, but the syntax they use does not line up with mine, is there a good way to pep8 it?

Example: I need to use a 3rd party module that I cannot edit and their naming convention isn't so great.

Example:

```
thisIsABase_function(self,a,b)
```

I have some code that pepifies the name to pep8, but I was wondering how I can make the functions accessible by that new pep8 name?

```
def _pep8ify(name):
    """PEP8ify name"""
    import re
    if '.' in name:
        name = name[name.rfind('.') + 1:]
    if name[0].isdigit():
        name = "level_" + name
    name = name.replace(".", "_")
    if '_' in name:
        return name.lower()
    s1 = re.sub('(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)', r'\1_\2', name)
    return re.sub('([a-z0-9])([A-Z])', r'\1_\2', s1).lower()
```

Is there a way I can PEP8 these names on import?

Comment: Just curious: How exactly would you apply that pepification function?

Comment: That seems like more trouble than it's worth… But why not `from third_party import fooBar_function as whatever_you_want`?

Comment: @deceze there are about 100 functions to import so that's not really an option... I guess that's a worst case option though.

Comment: @tobias_k that's my question.

Comment: I guess you could write a script that imports all the names from a module, "pepifies" those names and creates a Python script, say `pepified_third_party_module` with one `from ... import ... as ...` for each of the names. Then, just import the pepified module instead of the original module.

Comment: Are you aware your `_pep8ify` doesn't handle classes appropriately as it is now?

Answer (score 6):

You can use a context manager to automatically pep8ify the symbols from an imported module like:

#### Example:

```
with Pep8Importer():
    import funky
```

#### Code:

```
class Pep8Importer(object):

    @staticmethod
    def _pep8ify(name):
        """PEP8ify name"""
        import re
        s1 = re.sub('(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)', r'\1_\2', name)
        return re.sub('([a-z0-9])([A-Z])', r'\1_\2', s1).lower()

    def __enter__(self):
        # get list of current modules in namespace
        self.orig_names = set(dir(sys.modules[__name__]))

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        """ Pep8ify names in any new modules

        Diff list of current module names in namespace.
        pep8ify names at the first level in those modules
        Ignore any other new names under the assumption that they
        were imported/created with the name as desired.
        """
        if exc_type is not None:
            return
        new_names = set(dir(sys.modules[__name__])) - self.orig_names
        for module_name in (n for n in new_names if not n.startswith('_')):
            module = sys.modules[module_name]
            for name in dir(module):
                pep8ified = self._pep8ify(name)
                if pep8ified != name and not name.startswith('_'):
                    setattr(module, pep8ified, getattr(module, name))
                    print("In mModule: {}, added '{}' from '{}'".format(
                        module_name, pep8ified, name))
```

#### Test Code:

```
with Pep8Importer():
    import funky

print(funky.thisIsABase_function)
print(funky.this_is_a_base_function)
```

#### funky.py

```
thisIsABase_function = 1
```

#### Results:

```
In module: funky, added 'this_is_a_base_function' from 'thisIsABase_function'

1
1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this does what you want:

```
# somemodule.py
def func_a():
    print('hello a')

def func_b():
    print('hello b')


# yourcode.py
import inspect
import importlib

def pepimports(the_module_name):
    mymodule = importlib.import_module(the_module_name)
    myfuncs = inspect.getmembers(f, inspect.isfunction)
    for f in myfuncs:
        setattr(mymodule, _pep8ify(f[1].__name__) , f[1])
    return mymodule

mymodule = pepimports('some_module_name')
# you can now call the functions from mymodule
# (the original names still exist, so watch out for clashes)
mymodule.pepified_function()
```

It's a bit hackish, but I've tried it (python 3.5) and it seems to work (at least on a trivial example).